# How do I inspect Pelican variables

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I'm modifying a Pelican template and I have the code below which adds url every time a page is found. I can see that the p object has the attributes url and title.

However I only knew this because I copied the code from another template shown below. Is there any way to inspect objects in jinja2 or Pelican to understand what information is contained within them?

```
      {% for p in pages %}
        <h1 class = "sidebar-title">
          <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ p.url }}">
          {{ p.title }}
          </a>
        </h1>
```

https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/blob/master/backdrop/templates/base.html

```
<li{% if p == page %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of an official resource explaining all variables, objects, attributes and properties in detail.

But for a start, I think the following start points suffice:

- [Common variables available for the standard templates](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/themes.html)
- [pelican.contents.py](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/contents.py):
  This is the module which contains (most of) the data structures pelican uses and which are made available in the templates. Have a look for properties (`@property`, these are functions which act like they are attributes) and attributes. At lines [367ff](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/contents.py#L367) there are some very simple subclass definitions which could be of use.
- [pelican.writers.py](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/writers.py): This module brings together the templating engine `jinja2`, the templates and the data to be inserted in the templates. Of special interest for you could be lines [138ff](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/writers.py#L138), as this seems like a good point to simply insert some small debug prints to see the real data which is present in the data structures.